# Writing an Encryption Algorithm in JCE

Tags: java, encryption, jce

I have a question regarding JCE encryption.  How do you write your own encryption algorithm/secret key generator in Java that can be installed as a .jar file in the ext directory?  I have the basic idea for the algorithm figured out but I don't know how to implement it.  Do I subclass Cipher and KeyGenerator?  Google yields no help, which I find funny.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the BouncyCastle Java library to see how they do it.  http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create your own provider for classes like `Cipher`. Those providers need to be signed with a private key which is part of a key pair trusted by Oracle.

You can find more information [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html).

Answer (score -1):

Your class should extend the abstract class [`javax.crypto.Provider`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/security/Provider.html).  The `Provider` class is the way to create new algorithms to be used by [`javax.crypto.Cipher`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).  Use the [`addProvider()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#getProvider%28%29) method of `Cipher` to make it available for use.